# Can Git rename matching ignore whitespace changes?

Tags: git

When I rename a file and do whitespace changes (such as changing the indentation), Git cannot recognize the rename. And I can't find any combination of `git diff` flags to get it to ignore whitespace while looking for renames. This makes reviewing otherwise simple refactorings difficult.

For example...

```
$ git init
$ ruby -e '100.times { puts "Basset hounds got long ears" }' > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m 'first commit'
$ git mv file file2
```

Everything is fine at this point.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    renamed:    file -> file2
```

Now if I indent the lines in the file Git no longer recognizes the rename.

```
$ ruby -i -pe 'gsub(/^/, "  ")' file2
$ git add .
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    file
    new file:   file2
```

After I commit `git diff -w HEAD^` still shows a delete and a new file. I can't find any `git diff` options which will recognize the rename.

Is there a set of options which allow Git to ignore whitespace when detecting copies and renames?

Comment: Short answer: no, the similarity index computation shares code with the internal xdelta computation and is on a byte-stream basis rather than line-by-line (except that it has a special hack to eat CRs after LFs).

Comment: It makes me sad that there is no way to do this. It's a lot harder to see what changed in certain kinds of refactors where there is an indentation change + file rename / move.

Answer (score 1):

Git cannot do this by default.

However, if you have the know-how, you can make it do so by changing the similarity index computation. The relevant code can be found [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/diffcore-delta.c) in `diffcore-delta.c` (which is well documented) and [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/diffcore-rename.c) in `diffcore-rename.c`.

Be aware that there are some starting checks and balances involved before Git even checks to see if a file can be considered as renamed (internally). This check will pass with a "yes" answer to the following question:

> Is it a regular non-zero sized file that has not significantly changed in file size?

One approach therefore is to add your conditional check before that point so that if there are only differences in whitespace then the similarity index computes to 100% otherwise Git should do what it normally does.

That said, what you experienced is why it often recommended that you rename the file first before changing its contents but names aren't that easy to get right the first time.

Comment: "it often recommended that you rename the file first before changing its contents."

FWIW, IMO there's not much point to this recommendation in the larger scheme of things, because when looking across multiple commits (e.g. in a GitHub PR, changes in a branch, etc.), rename detection still does not work. The rename is detected solely when looking at that single commit in isolation.

Comment: Nod "rename the file first before changing its contents" does not help.  Do not be fooled.